# Keep mysql database updated

Tags: php, mysql, diff

I'm currently developing a new site that will replace my client's current system. The plan is to move a small subset of the users over to the new site and then move the remaining users over after a month. During this time, the data for the new system will be cleaned up and added to, while the current system will still be under use. The new system has an entirely different database schema and I've written some php code to migrate the current system's data over to the new one. The problem is when when I need to re-migrate the data off the current site after a month I don't won't to overwrite any of the changes that have been made on the new site.

I was thinking something like this might work:

1. Migrate all of the data to the new database and make a backup of it.
2. Clean it up, add to it over the month then back it up just before step 3
3. Re-migrate all of the data off the current system, make back up
4. Somehow diff the data in steps 1 and 3.
5. Merge all of the new data from step 4 into the data from step 2.

Does this thought process make sense? Are there any better solutions? Steps 4 and 5 are where I'm a little murky on. I've looked around the forum a bit and it looks like there are some tools that may accomplish this (toad, command line diff). Does anyone have any experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to migrate it all at once. If you tested it completely, you should be fine.

Migrating a little piece of the database and a month later the rest is just a bad idea, diffing afterwards is (can be) just plain hell.

If the new system toooo different from the old one, you could execute your plan as well, but it can be a hassle.

Comment: Agreed, insofar as a direct migration will be easier from a database management perspective. I do see the value of running a pilot programme to test and prove the new system before making a complete cutover, but from a data integrity perspective it is a nightmare. Of course, how large a nightmare is dependent on the actual nature of the system - if there is no data shared between users, and everything is indexed against the userid it would be easy (just migrate the pilot users first and the rest later), but dealing with shared data? Messy no matter how you do it.